# SharePoint 2010 InfoPath Forms Library FileName

Tags: forms, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, form-library

I have a forms library in SharePoint 2010, and have designed the InfoPath form to add/update content to that library. Let's say that I have a field in the InfoPath form called "CustomFileName" - so that every time that field is updated, the InfoPath file's name is changed to that.

Instead, it is creating a new File/Entry every time the "CustomFileName" field is updated. I tried using Workflows, but it isn't an option since the CustomFileName values sometimes contains multiple periods that break the Workflow.

**Checklist:**

- In the Data Connection Wizard, I do have "CustomFileName" specified in the "File Name" field
- In the Submit rules, I do have a rule for when the "CustomFileName" is empty - to use a Name+".xml" notation

We need the file name to be renamed instead of creating a new file every time. Over-writing is okay, as long as we can trace the version history.

Any help here would be much appreciated.